# True or false about existence of solution for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $x'=f(x,t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\gamma(t)$ a soluitino for the ODE such that $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(1)=x_{0}$. So, given a neighborhood $U_{x_{0}}$ of $x_{0}$, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that, if $g(x,t)$ satisfies $|g(x,t)-f(x,t)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ and $t$, so the solution $\eta(t)$ of $x'=g(x,t)$ such that $\eta(0)=0$ satisfies $\eta(1)\in U_{x_{0}}$.

Is this statement true or false? Intuitively, seems true, but I don't know how to demonstrate.

Comment: If you assume moreover that $f$ (or $g$) is globally Lipschitz in $x$, with the Lipschitz constant $\le M$, then yes, [the integral form of Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions) seems to give $\lvert\eta(t)-\gamma(t)\rvert<\epsilon t e^{Mt}$.

Answer (score 1):

** When $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ do not depend on $x$ this works:

$|\dot\eta(t) - \dot \gamma(t)| = |f(t)-g(t)|<\epsilon$, so integrate $-\epsilon < \dot \eta(t) - \dot \gamma(t)  < \epsilon$

and use that $\eta(0) = \gamma(0) = 0$ to get:

$|\eta(t) - \gamma(t) | < \epsilon t$.

Then set $t = 1$ to get that $\eta(1)$ is $\epsilon$-close to $x_0 = \gamma(1)$.

So, for a general neighborhood of $x_0$, it will depend on $t$ (how far you want to send the solutions) and how good your bound $\epsilon$ for $|f - g|$ is. In the worst case, an $O(\epsilon)$ perturbation can have an $O(1)$ effect on solutions within time scale $O(1/\epsilon)$ (but of course for certain examples things could be better)

**edit: thanks to LutzL and user539887's comments, we need to add conditions on how to compare $f(x,t)$ and $g(y,t)$ when $x\ne y$. For example, when $f$ has a Lipschitz condition $|f(x,t) - f(y,t)|\le M|x-y|$, here is a way we can work out some bounds:

Set $u(t) = \eta(t) - \gamma(t)$, then $u(0) = 0$ and

$|\dot u| = |g(\eta(t), t) - f(\gamma(t), t) + f(\eta(t), t) - f(\eta(t), t)|<\epsilon + M |u|$.

then compare directly with solutions of $\dot u_+ = \epsilon + M|u_+|, \dot u_- = -\epsilon - M|u_-|$ to get

$-\frac{\epsilon}{M}(e^{Mt} - 1) = u_-(t) \le u(t) \le u_+(t) = \frac{\epsilon}{M}(e^{Mt} - 1)$ for $t\ge 0$

Or $|u(t)|\le \frac{\epsilon}{M}(e^{Mt}-1)$ for $t\ge 0$.

Comment: That way I can solve for $U_{x_{0}}$ being an open ball.
If $U_{x_{0}}$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of $x_{0}$, can I take $\epsilon>0$ such that the ball $B(x_{0},\epsilon)$ is contained in $U_{x_{0}}$?

Comment: Exactly. That $\epsilon$ will work.

Comment: How do you get the bound for $|f(t,γ(t))-g(t,η(t))|$? There is nothing mentioned that allows to compare function values at different $x$-arguments.

Comment: Here's a counterexample to your claim in the first display: take $f(x,t)=x$ and $g(x,t)=x+\epsilon$. $f$ and $g$ are $\epsilon$-close, but, for $\eta(0)=\gamma(0)=0$ you have $\eta(t)\equiv0$ and $\gamma(t)=\epsilon(e^t-1)$, which gives $\lvert\eta(t)-\gamma(t)\rvert=\epsilon(e^t-1)>\epsilon t$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: oops! Thank you for catching my carelessness. I guess I was just thinking of when $\dot x = f(t), g(t)$...